# Update a facebook app and submission

Tags: facebook

I have created a facebook app and it is approved after submission. So now I can enable the app. But what are the steps when I would like to update the app with an facebook (Open Graph) functionality that has to be approved?

When I add the functionality to the live enviroment all users will see and be able to use this new functionality (that not yet has been approved so won;t work). But for the submission the live version should be updated. There must be an better way to do this?

Facebook doesn't provide an acceptation enviroment so the live version would change before approvement. Are there any possibilities to do this?

Comment: If the open graph story is not already approved just add one and submit it for approval. If it is already approved I'm pretty sure that any change you do to it will only effect people that have a role on the app. Until it gets approved again then it becomes available to everyone

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear:
"When I add the functionality to the live enviroment all users will see and be able to use this new functionality (that not yet has been approved so won;t work). But for the submission the live version should be updated. There must be an better way to do this?"